# Angular 9 not setting up a dynamic input field value

Tags: typescript, angular9

There is a weird issue coming after upgrading to angular 9 version.
I am calling a function which returns a value to set default value for input form field.
The function is returning a value, but in the input box it's not showing that value instead it's displaying as **[object object]**
Surprisingly if I call the same function in [placeholder] it displays correct return value.
I have no clue, why is it working fine with [placeholder], but not in the [value].
The same was working fine in angular 8.

html file

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput formControlName="{{'item'+k}}" [placeholder]="getValue(k)"  [value]="getValue(k)" />
</mat-form-field>
```

ts file

```
getValue(k:any) {
  let item;
  // ... some logic to get a desired value
  return item;
}
```

Comment: Have you found its solution yet? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the input decorator to initialize your input value.

In ts file, set property value, ie: this.property = item and initialize using @input decorator then in html, use the ngModel directive to bind the component value to property.

Remember, you cannot use ngModel with value property in the same element.

Answer (score 0):

You are using reactive forms and Value set property at same time which is not preferred.

Please check the following and if this isn't what you asking for, please provide more info so we could help! https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhcini